# Opening PWA inside in App browser

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am new to ionic and PWA.
I am trying to open a PWA (www.flipkart.com) using "InAppBrowser" [window.open('https://flipkart.com','_blank'); ]
When the PWA opens in "InAppBrowser", it fluctuates between "offline" and "online (internet connection is ON all time. This fluctuation occur by itself)

But the same PWA if we open in system browser there is no such fluctuation and behavior is smooth. [window.open('https://flipkart.com','_system','location=yes'); ].

Is there any issue in "InAppBrowser" to handle PWA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

first, App open a webview to show the webpage, it takes time. Maybe that's why it fluctuates between "offline" and "online